# Find a number $a$ such that $f(x)=\sin(x+\pi/4)$ with $a\leq x\leq a+\pi,$ has an inverse

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Sorry, this question looks trivial but it's actually from someone close by.

> Find a number $a$ such that the function $f(x)=\sin(x+\pi/4)$ with domain $a\leq x\leq a+\pi$ has an inverse

**My trial**

Let $y=f(x)$, then \begin{align}y=\sin(x+\pi/4)&\iff x+\pi/4=\arcsin y\iff x=\arcsin y-\pi/4\\&\quad f^{-1}y=\arcsin y-\pi/4.\end{align}

However, how do I deal with the interval $a\leq x\leq a+\pi$, to get the requested value of $a?$

Comment: You are asked to find an interval of length $\pi$ where the function $\sin(x+\pi/4)$ is invertible. Why don't you just sketch the graph of this function and pick such an interval?

Comment: @uniquesolution: Oh yes, you have truly spoken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $\sin:[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ is injective, so you need that
$$-\frac\pi2=a+\frac\pi4$$

Of course you can start with any interval where $\sin$ is injective, like $[\pi/2,3\pi/2]$, etc.